# powershell how to setup parameter as variables

Tags: powershell

Powershell how to setup parameter as variable ?

The code like this:

```
get-stat -Entity (get-vmhost ) -Disk -Start 'date-time' -Finish 'date-time'
```

For parameter -Disk, there are other options can be used. I want to setup this parameter as a variable by the following so I can choose what to run for.

```
$item = read-host -prompt 'Select Disk, CPU, Network or Common'
get-stat -Entity (get-vmhost ) -$item -Start 'date-time' -Finish 'date-time'
```

But it wont work returning error message "A positional parameter can't be found"

Any solution to that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [PowerShell Splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675931.aspx) a way of bundling parameters to send to a command:

```
$item = read-host -prompt 'Select Disk, CPU, Network or Common'
$aB = @{$item = $true;
       Entity = (get-vmhost );
       Start = 'date-time';
       Finish  = 'date-time'}
get-stat @aB
```

Comment: it wont work, return error message "true : The term 'true' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again"

Comment: `true` should either be `"true"` or `'true'` (if it's meant to be a string) or `$true` (if it's meant to be a boolean true/false value)